# CodeIgniter get extra value from form_dropdown function

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I used a form_dropdown in a my form. The point is I have to attached with the selection an ID. So I would like to send with my form_dropdow.

Here is the code from my view :

```
$options = array(
    'NULL'      => 'Choose an answer',
    'TRUE'      => 'Yes',
    'FALSE'     => 'No',
);
```

`echo form_dropdown('event', $options, 'NULL');`

I tried to pass the value in the 4th parameters like that :

```
`echo form_dropdown('event', $options, 'NULL', $row['id']);`
```

But I don't know how to get this value from my controller.

Comment: There is no 4th argument to the `form_dropdown` function. Are you trying to make it so that the `$row['id']` is updated with either `null/true/false`?

Comment: Really? But in the documentation, there is an $extra value :http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_dropdown#form_dropdown. Otherwise, yes I want to update with the $row['id'].

Comment: Sorry, my apologies. I didn't have the version of CI correct when I was peaking.